# Angular what's the meaning of these three dots in @NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx

What do these three dots mean exactly, and why do I need them?

```
export function leadReducer(state: Lead[]= [], action: Action {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_LEAD:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case REMOVE_LEAD:
            return state.filter(lead => lead.id !== action.payload.id )
}
}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The three dots are known as the [spread operator](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator) from Typescript (also from [ES7](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

The spread operator return all elements of an array. Like you would write each element separately:

```
let myArr = [1, 2, 3];
return [1, 2, 3];
//is the same as:
return [...myArr];
```

This is mostly just syntactic sugar as it compiles this:

```
func(...args);
```

to this:

```
func.apply(null, args);
```

In your case this gets compiled to this:

```
return [...state, action.payload];
//gets compiled to this:
return state.concat([action.payload]);
```

Comment: I fail to see the difference between myArr, [1,2,3], [...myArr]

Comment: @JohnDemetriou That's because it's the same. But `[myArr]` wouldn't be the same as `myArr`.   The spread operator "spreads" the element of an array like arguments. `...[1, 2, 3]` results in `1, 2, 3`, which would, obviously, be the same if you put it in an array once more.

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = (arr => [...arr])(a); c = (arr => arr)(a); a.push('a'); b.push('b'); c.push('c');` Just returning myArr (c) returns the same array, using the spread operator to create a new array (b) creates a separate object with the same contents. Since c is the same array instance as a, after this a and c are both [1,2,3,'a','c'] and b is [1,2,3,'b'].

Answer (score 50):

It is a spread operator (...) which is used for **spreading the element of an array/object or for initializing an array or object from another array or object**.

Let's create new array from existing array to understand this.

> let Array1 = [ 1, 2, 3];       //1,2,3
>
> let Array2 = [ 4, 5, 6];       //4,5,6
>
> ***//Create new array from existing array***
>
> let copyArray = [...Array1];
>   //1,2,3
>
> ***//Create array by merging two arrays***
>
> let mergedArray = [...Array1, ...Array2];   //1,2,3,4,5,6
>
> ***//Create new array from existing array + more elements***
>
> let newArray = [...Array1, 7, 8];             //1,2,3,7,8

Comment: Clearest answer for those with no prior knowledge, thank you.

Comment: @Shweta So what does `let copyArray = Array1;` ?

Comment: @AteSomebits It will also create a new array naming "CopyArray" having same elements as in "Array1". Basically same copy of Array1 will be done.

Answer (score 9):

The `...`([*spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) works by returning each value from index `0` to index `length-1`:

Answer (score 1):

**Context:** Take care of this particular behavior (by value / by reference) of the three dots spread syntax, when working with sub-arrays (or any other second level properties).

**Finding:** Take care that nested arrays (or sub-properties) are NOT passed by value, but by reference. In other words, only first level items are passed as a copy "by value". See the example:

```js
sourceArray = [ 1, [2, 3] ] // Second element is a sub-array
targetArray = [ ...sourceArray]
console.log("Target array result:", JSON.stringify(targetArray), "\n\n") //it seems a copy, but...

console.log("Let's update the first source value:\n")
sourceArray[0] = 10
console.log("Updated source array:", JSON.stringify(sourceArray), "\n")
console.log("Target array is NOT updated, It keeps a copy by value:")
console.log(JSON.stringify(targetArray), "\n\n")

//But if you update a value of the sub-array, it has NOT been copied
console.log("Finally, let's update a nested source value:\n")
sourceArray[1][0] = 20
console.log("Updated source nested array:", JSON.stringify(sourceArray), "\n")
console.log("Target array is updated BY REFERENCE! ", )
console.log(JSON.stringify(targetArray), "\n\n") // it is not a copy, it is a reference!

console.log("CONCLUSION: ... spread syntax make a copy 'by value' for first level elements, but 'by reference' for second level elements (This applies also for objects) so take care!\n")
```