# What does this expression means? this.activeScenario = { ...scenario };

Tags: angular

i have some existing coe that contains this expression and i can not understand how does it work.
please can anyone explain to me the expression please?
this.activeScenario = { ...scenario };

Comment: this is the Typescript spread operator, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235436/angular-whats-meaning-of-three-dots-in-ngrx

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax as well

Comment: Thank you so much i really appreciate it